# Php application encoding problems from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I am trying to encode php application from ISO-8859-1 to UTF-8. Made a test copy of the application, ran the following iconv to recursively modify all files.

```
find . -type f -print -exec iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 -o {}.converted {} \; -exec mv {}.converted {} \;
```

The above did not really do the work. The code still has text like:

```
nÃ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃ§Ã£o. serÃ¡ setado adequadadmente
```

With a test php script

```
<?php
$text = "nÃ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃ§Ã£o. serÃ¡ setado adequadadmente";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("ISO-8859-1", "UTF-8", $text), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

the output is:

```
Original : nÃ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃ§Ã£o. serÃ¡ setado adequadadmente
TRANSLIT : nÃƒÂ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o. serÃƒÂ¡ setado adequadadmente
IGNORE   : nÃƒÂ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o. serÃƒÂ¡ setado adequadadmente
Plain    : nÃƒÂ£o exibe nenhuma info durante a configuraÃƒÂ§ÃƒÂ£o. serÃƒÂ¡ setado adequadadmente
```

Comment: Are you sure that your original code is ISO8859-1? It rather looks like you "double converted" to UTF-8 (i.e. told iconv to read UTF-8 as ISO8859-1 and convert it to UTF-8)

Comment: Indeed `nÃ£` is already UTF-8, but you will have to tell your browser it is.

Comment: is it possible to replace it with regular characters

Comment: Restore your backup and start from the beginning. You've made something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your files are fine and in UTF-8, you are just interpreting it in CP1252/ISO-8859-1.  You need to declare encoding to the browser and your text editor.

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
```

In your text editor, specify that the file is in UTF-8, and it will show the characters correctly. Do not do any conversions.